# Swift Assign the .setBackgroundImage from Dictionary

Tags: swift, ios8

In the plist file of my project i save the various images through a dictionary.
This dictionary I can do it in two ways:

```
1)  [mm:photo1, Ed:photo2, as:photo3]
```

or

```
2)  [mm: <UIImage: 0x7fa822540580> size {1024, 768} orientation 0 scale 1.000000, 
     Ed: <UIImage: 0x7fe820474c30> size {1024, 768} orientation 0 scale 1.000000, 
     as: <UIImage: 0x7fe82064d300> size {1024, 768} orientation 0 scale 1.000000]
```

I can get the keys in this way

```
var ButtonImageReload = data!["ButtonImage"] as? Dictionary<String, String>
            if var b = ButtonImageReload {
                var rek: AnyObject? = b["\(namePlist[index])"]
                newButton .setBackgroundImage(rek, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                }
```

I tried in this mode with 2) but don't go !!! 
how should I save the images through the method 1 or 2, and how can I assign the .setBackgroundImage to newButton ?

UPDATE 
I HAVE SOLVE WITH 1 MODE :

```
var ButtonImageReload = data!["ButtonImage"] as? Dictionary<String, String>
            if var b = ButtonImageReload {
                var rek: AnyObject! = b["\(namePlist[index])"]
                var loadImage = UIImage(named: "\(rek)") as UIImage!
                newButton .setBackgroundImage(loadImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: What are `mm`, `Ed` and `as`(a keyword! how could that work??)?

Comment: yes a keyword , i have solve and i edit the Question ...